# Get list of country IDs for google's public holidays calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API V3.

I am trying to list all holidays for a selected country like so
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.uk%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=mykey

But first I need to build a select with all supported country IDs.
I found a list of country IDs here:
https://gist.github.com/mattn/1438183

Is there an API call that can fetch all supported country IDs for google's public holidays calendar?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Did anyone get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated on January 2020 list ISO 3166-2 to google calendar name:

IMPORTANT! For all not listed countries ISO 3166-2 is used so i.e. for Albania it is al.

```
        {"au", "australian"},
        {"at", "austrian"},
        {"br", "brazilian"},
        {"bg", "bulgarian"},
        {"ca", "canadian"},
        {"cn", "china"},
        {"hr", "croatian"},
        {"cz", "czech"},
        {"dk", "danish"},
        {"fi", "finnish"},
        {"fr", "french"},
        {"de", "german"},
        {"gr", "greek"},
        {"hk", "hong_kong"},
        {"hu", "hungarian"},
        {"in", "indian"},
        {"id", "indonesian"},
        {"ie", "irish"},
        {"il", "jewish"},
        {"it", "italian"},
        {"jp", "japanese"},
        {"lv", "latvian"},
        {"lt", "lithuanian"},
        {"my", "malaysia"},
        {"mx", "mexican"},
        {"nl", "dutch"},
        {"nz", "new_zealand"},
        {"no", "norwegian"},
        {"ph", "philippines"},
        {"pl", "polish"},
        {"pt", "portuguese"},
        {"ro", "romanian"},
        {"ru", "russian"},
        {"sa", "saudiarabian"},
        {"sg", "singapore"},
        {"sk", "slovak"},
        {"si", "slovenian"},
        {"kr", "south_korea"},
        {"es", "spain"},
        {"se", "swedish"},
        {"tw", "taiwan"},
        {"tl", "thai"},
        {"tr", "turkish"},
        {"ua", "ukrainian"},
        {"us", "usa"},
        {"vn", "vietnamese"}
```